# Converting python dataframe to a particular JSON structute

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

Hi i want to convert my dataframe to a specific json structure. my dataframe look something like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["file1", "1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9", 91, "RMLO"], ["file2", "1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9", 92, "LMLO"], ["file3", "1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9", 93, "LCC"], ["file4", "1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9", 94, "RCC"]], columns=["Filename", "StudyID", "probablity", "finding_name"])
```

And the json structure in which i want to convert my datafram is below :

```
{
            "findings": [
                            {
                                "name": "RMLO",
                                "probability": "91"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "LMLO",
                                "probability": "92"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "LCC",
                                "probability": "93"
                            }
                            {
                                "name": "LCC93",
                                "probability" : "94"
                            }
                        ],
            "status": "Processed",
            "study_id": "1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.0"
        }
```

i tried implementing this with below code with different orient variables but i didn't get what i wanted.

```
j = df[["probablity","findings"]].to_json(orient='records')
```

so if any can help in achiveing this..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this similar to what you are trying to achieve:

```
import json
j = df[["finding_name","probablity"]].to_json(orient='records')
study_id = df["StudyID"][0]
j_dict = {"findings": json.loads(j), "status": "Processed", "study_id": study_id}
j_dict
```

This results in:

```
{'findings': [{'finding_name': 'RMLO', 'probablity': 91},
  {'finding_name': 'LMLO', 'probablity': 92},
  {'finding_name': 'LCC', 'probablity': 93},
  {'finding_name': 'RCC', 'probablity': 94}],
 'status': 'Processed',
 'study_id': '1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9'}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is close but in findings i need just finding name which in this case is "RMLO,LMLO,LCC,RCC" and there respective probabilities. There's No need of filename in json and since study ID is and will be same for each column there's no need to o out in a json list, it will be like ```study_id : '1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9' ```